# Demean R data frame

Tags: r, plyr

I would like to demean multiple columns in an R `data.frame`. Using an example from [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46978/fixed-effects-using-demeaned-data-why-different-standard-errors-when-using-plm)

```
set.seed(999)
library(plyr)
library(plm)
# random data.frame
dat <- expand.grid(id=factor(1:3), cluster=factor(1:6))
dat <- cbind(dat, x=runif(18), y=runif(18, 2, 5))

#demean x and y
dat.2 <- ddply(dat, .(cluster), transform, x=x-mean(x), y=y-mean(y))
```

My problem is that I have (lots) more than 2 variables, and I would like to avoid hard-coding this analysis. I'm new to `plyr` in general; why does this

```
dat.2 <- ddply(dat[,c(x,y)],  .(cluster), transform, function(x) x - mean(x))
```

not work? Is there some crucial step that I'm missing? Is there a better way to do this in general?

Comment: you could melt your data.frame into long format, `m = melt(dat, id=c("cluster", "id")); ddply(m, c("cluster", "variable"), mutate, value = value - mean(value))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the `colwise` functor. The only thing to be careful about is that `id` column. Hence:

```
demean <- colwise(function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) x - mean(x) else x)
dat.2 <- ddply(dat, .(cluster), demean)
```

Edit: as you found, there is even a `numcolwise` functor for only dealing with numerics so you can do:

```
demean <- numcolwise(function(x) x - mean(x))
dat.2 <- ddply(dat, .(cluster), demean)
```

You can also use the `scale` function rather than define your own function:

```
dat.2 <- ddply(dat, .(cluster), numcolwise(scale, scale = FALSE))
```

Comment: Cool... would `numcolwise` (just reading the `?` dialog) obviate the need for the `if(...)` statement?